# How to init char array using char literals?

Tags: java, char

The following statement doesn't work in Java, but works in C:

```
char c[] = "abcdefghijklmn";
```

What's wrong?

Does the char array can only be initialized as following?

```
char c[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'};
```

Comment: It should be String str="something"; for Java. You can use toCharArray() method of String class to get the char[].

Comment: There's nothing wrong, those are just two different languages.

Comment: It doesn't work because Java has a real String class, not just a null terminated array of chars like C.

Comment: char[] is generally useless in Java. You will use String class in Java more than you will ever touch char[]

Comment: Or use StringBuilder if you want a mutable `char[]`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could use

```
char c[] = "abcdefghijklmn".toCharArray();
```

if you don't mind creating an unnecessary String.

Unlike in C, Strings are objects, and not just arrays of characters.

That said, it's quite rare to use char arrays directly. Are you sure you don't want a String instead?

Comment: The primitive types are not enough to represent all data types comparing to C?

Comment: All objects are built from basic data types, String included. But the point of using objects is that they offer a much richer API than basic data types. Want to remove whitespace from the beginning and end, use `trim()`. Want to search for a substring, use `indexOf()`. Want to split on separators, use `split()`. Want to make sure accesses to the String from concurrent threads is safe: no problem: String is thread-safe and immutable, unlike a char array. Why use a char array and reimplement all this by yourself?

Answer (score 11):

You can initialize it from a String:

```
char[] c = "abcdefghijklmn".toCharArray();
```

However, if what you need is a string, you should simply use a string:

```
String s = "abcdefghijklmn";
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use String toCharArray(), then yes, a char array must be initialized like any other array- `char[] c = new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n'};`

Answer (score 2):

The literal "abcdefghijklmn" is a String object in Java. You can quickly convert this into a char array by using the String toCharArray() method.

Try this:

```
char[] c = "abcdefghijklmn".toCharArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String a = "abcdefghijklmn";   
char[] c = a.toCharArray();
```